# PDFCreator set "PDF Producer" meta attribute

Tags: pdf, metadata, vbscript, ghostscript

I am trying to find a way to create a PDF using pdfcreator and set the PDF Producer to something other than ghostscript v*.

For some odd reason the program I am piping the Pdf file to will only accept canon generated PDF files.

I thought there might be some sort of ghostscript parameter I could pass but have not found anything obvious. I even looked at passing the pdf to a vbscript to modify that property but I don't off hand see any object I can create to modify it.

Any ideas or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), which allows you to, as implied by it's name, change [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format)  tags. I've tested the Windows version thusly:

`"exiftool(-k).exe" -"Producer"="Canon" <name of PDF to modify>`

Where `<name of PDF to modify>` is the file for which you would like to change the "Producer" tag. Of course, you can change the data in the tag to whatever it's convenient for you.

Comment: Thank you, This worked thru a manual command line as a quick test. I suspect I can throw it in a vbs wrapper to do the whole deal I need.

Answer (score 4):

I found a freeware tool called pdf info (if you prefer a gui) at beaureausoft.com. Sorry, I'm not promoting the tool! It helped me.

Edit: after testing, exiftool has fewer bugs. PDF Info inserts garbage in the field "[[[[000". It's worth investing in learning it's command line parameters:

```
exiftool -"Producer"="Adobe PDF Library 9.0" -"Creator"="Adobe InDesign CS4 (6.0.6)" file.pdf
```